# CSS content class rather than attr

Tags: jquery, css, class, attr

I'd like to pass in existing markup to a tool tip built with css, currently using attr(title) but having to duplicate the markup for desired results.

consider:

```
<p class="toolTip" title="this is a tooltip">hover over me</p>
<p class="existing">this is a tool tip</p>


.toolTip:hover:after{
    content: attr(title);
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
.toolTip:hover:after{
    content: class(existing);  //invalid I know!
}
```

tl:dr; I'd like to pull in content from existing markup using a class, rather than using the title attribute.

Comment: Are you suggesting inheritance? If  yes then it is not possible in traditional css3. You have to use LESS preprocessor for that.

Comment: Why the class attribute in particular?

Comment: @i_like_robots doesn't have to be class, but the element in question only has class on it.  Could be anything, as long as I don't need to duplicate all the markup.

Comment: @Harry could this be done with jQuery?  I'd happily run a couple of lines of jQuery to achieve this.  Anything that saves people having to edit to areas of markup in the future.

Comment: What exactly are you *duplicating* here? You're just *moving* text to a title attribute

Comment: @Danield I don't want to move the text, as the text is used on site currently.  (in a different area, hidden where the tooltip exists).

Comment: Thanks @Harry I think I'll have to achieve this using jQuery, no biggie! :)

Comment: @Harry happy for you to post as answer :)

Comment: @Myles: I have posted an answer mate. I am removing the previous comments because they are now already in the answer and also adding jQuery tag to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pure CSS (or even with pre-processors) there is no real way to pick the entire text content of an element and assign it to the `content` attribute. The [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) attribute can have only pre-defined string, URL, value of an attribute or a counter as values.

You can use jQuery (or plain vanilla JS) to automatically add the `toolTip` class and the `title` attribute to all elements that have the required class (`.existing`) and assign the text content of the element to that attribute. This way you do not have to duplicate the CSS rules.

> Note: This is just a simple example on how to set the content of an element to its title attribute but in real world scenario you would need more because there is not much point in setting the actual content itself as tooltip.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.existing').addClass('toolTip');
  $('.existing').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).text());
  });
});
```

```css
.toolTip:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  /* just for demo */
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="toolTip" title="this is a tooltip">hover over me</p>
<p class="existing">this is a tool tip</p>
```

---

**A Different Example:** This is a slightly different sample where the tooltip is different from the content of the element. Here the content of the element is the content of the parent and the tooltip text is initially present in the child (with `class="existing"`). Using jQuery the content of this child `span` is added to the `title` attribute of the parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.existing').parent().addClass('toolTip');
  $('.existing').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().attr('title', $(this).text());
  });
});
```

```css
.toolTip:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  /* just for demo */
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.existing {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="toolTip" title="this is a tooltip">hover over me</p>
<p>hover over me <span class="existing">this is a tool tip</span>
</p>

<div>I have a tooltip too<span class="existing">See, I told you!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Always glad to be of help pal @Myles